# When using read.csv to import a csv file I get different formats of a date variable on different computers

Tags: r, csv

I have different computers where I use r and an identical data file in .csv format.  The source of the file is found here within a compressed folder: https://divvybikes.com/assets/images/Divvy_Stations_Trips_2013.zip

After extraction, I copy the file called *Divvy_Trips_2013.csv* to my working directory. This file has two time/date variables *starttime* and *stoptime*

In some cases I get the following:

```
> data <- read.csv("Divvy_Trips_2013.csv")
> str(data$starttime)
Factor w/ 176405 levels "10/10/2013 0:02",..: 80251 80256 80259 80260 80262 80284 80273 80282 80286 80287 
> data[1,1:3]
  trip_id       starttime        stoptime
1    4118 6/27/2013 12:11 6/27/2013 12:16
```

In other cases I get the following:

```
> data <- read.csv("Divvy_Trips_2013.csv")
> str(data$starttime)
Factor w/ 176405 levels "2013-06-27 01:06",..: 7 12 15 16 18 40 29 38 42 43 ...
> data[1,1:3]
  trip_id        starttime         stoptime
1    4118 2013-06-27 12:11 2013-06-27 12:16
```

When I open up the file in a text editor I see as an example of the first entry:

```
4118,6/27/2013 12:11,6/27/2013 12:16,480,316,42,Michigan Ave & Oak St,282,Larrabee St & Menomonee St,Customer,,
```

I am wondering if there is any explanation about the date formatting discrepancies and what I might need to do to insure uniform formatting so it always looks like the first example.

I will note that I  tried hosting the *Divvy_Trips_2013.csv* on dropbox and ran the `read.csv` with the dropbox public URL and it worked fine on all machines. I am curious, however, to know why I am getting the discrepancy on different local machines.

Comment: when loading the csv file be sure to include `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `read.csv` command so you can control the formatting manually.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like the date as read in is the same in your both examples. What differs is the formatting of the date. Please check if `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` differs on the different computers.

I second @Gary Weissmann's advise to use `stringAsFactors=FALSE` as parameter to `read.csv`. An alternative good practise in my opinion is to use the `colClasses` parameter and declare the expected data type for each column. This way, you get a error message if the data does not comply with your expectations.